# Dojo Charting MoveSlice, change event from hover to onclick

Tags: dojox.charting

I am creating Pie Charts with Dojo and would like to use the MoveSlice action, but would like it to happen onclick instead of onhover.  Is there an easy way to to do this?

MoveSlice example: http://user.sitepen.com/~dwalsh/dojo-charting.html#piechart

MoveSlice js: http://support.freenas.org/browser/freenas/branches/dojo17/gui/dojango/dojo-media/release/1.7.0/dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice.js?rev=8478

Thanks

Comment: Clone MoveSlice, and do whatever you like with events.